# Nonlocal interaction effects on bose-einstein condensates

Tags: experimental-physics, potential, bose-einstein-condensate, 1pi-effective-action

I'm studying an interacting bose-einstein condensate using the energy functional proposed in this paper

K. Huang, C.N. Yang, Phys. Rev. **105**

$$
E\left[\phi\right] = \int d^3\vec{r} \left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}|\nabla\phi|^2 + \phi^*\left[U(x,y,z)+\frac{g}{4}\left| \phi \right|^2 + \frac{g_2}{4}\nabla^2\left(\left|\phi\right|^2\right)\right]\phi \right\}
$$
where
$$
g = \frac{4\pi \hbar^2 a}{m} \qquad g_2 = \frac{4\pi\hbar^2 a^2(\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{1}{2}r_e)}{m}
$$
$a$ is the scattering lenght, $r_e$ the effective range of the potential.

1) why in the kinetic term is there the square of gradient of $\phi$ and not $\phi^*\nabla^2\phi$?

2) How can i get the relation between $a$ and $r_e$ in this special case? Authors use directly the relation for hard-sphere potential $r_e = 2/3a$ but i don't understand why. In the functional there isn't a hard-sphere potential...

3) I've calculated the dispersion relation for waves inside a condensate trapped in one dimension(i've written $\phi(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma}\varphi(z)e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}$ and i've integrated the functional over $x,y$ )
$$
\omega = k\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}\left( n_0\tilde{\gamma} - \left( \tilde{\gamma_2}n_0-\frac{\hbar^2}{4m}\right) k^2\right)}
$$
where $\tilde{\gamma}$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_2$ depend on the confinement strength, 
I'd like to check if there is consistence with experimental data. do you suggest me anything?